# Finding Longest Palindromic Substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

The following code finds the longest palindromic sub string:

```js
function longestPalindromicSubstring(string) {
  // Write your code here.

  let longestPalindrome = "";

  let left = 0;
  let right = 0;

  //  find odd length
  for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
    left = right = index;
    while (string[left] === string[right]) {
      if (right - left + 1 >= longestPalindrome.length) {
        longestPalindrome = string.substring(left, right + 1);
      }
      left--;
      right++;
    }
  }

  //   find even length
  for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
    left = index;
    right = left + 1;
    while (string[left] === string[right]) {
      if (right - left + 1 >= longestPalindrome.length) {
        longestPalindrome = string.substring(left, right + 1);
      }
      left--;
      right++;
    }
  }

  return longestPalindrome;
}

console.log(longestPalindromicSubstring("abaxyzzyxf"));
```

Output:

```bash
xyzzyx
```

The answer is correct. However, when I try to run it in a testing environment, it got failed with out of memory error. What the issue?

Comment: If the input string is a million characters long, the code will call `string.substring` many times, using a lot of memory. There's no reason to repeatedly call `string.substring`. Just keep track of the best indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not handle large strings well. For each character in the input string, it potentially creates *substrings*, which can lead to a significant memory usage and slow performance, especially for long input strings.

You can optimize the code and avoid running into memory errors, by implementing  a more efficient algorithm, such as Manacher's algorithm. Manacher's algorithm is designed specifically for finding the longest palindromic substring and has a time complexity of *O(n)*, where n is the length of the input string.

**Code Example:**

```js
function longestPalindromicSubstring(string) {
  if (string === null || string.length === 0) {
    return "";
  }

  //preprocess the input string to handle even-length palindromes
  let processedString = "^#"; //start with two special characters (^ and #)

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    //insert # between each character in the input string
    processedString += string[i] + "#";
  }

  processedString += "$"; //end the processed string with a special character ($)

  let center = 0;
  let right = 0;
  const P = new Array(processedString.length).fill(0); //initialize an array to store palindrome lengths

  //calculate the palindrome lengths using Manacher's algorithm
  for (let i = 1; i < processedString.length - 1; i++) {
    const mirror = 2 * center - i;

    if (i < right) {
      P[i] = Math.min(right - i, P[mirror]);
    }

    let a = i + (1 + P[i]);
    let b = i - (1 + P[i]);

    while (processedString[a] === processedString[b]) {
      P[i]++;
      a++;
      b--;
    }

    if (i + P[i] > right) {
      center = i;
      right = i + P[i];
    }
  }

  //find the maximum palindrome length and its center
  const maxLen = Math.max(...P);
  const maxLenIndex = P.indexOf(maxLen);

  //calculate the start and end indices of the longest palindromic substring
  const start = Math.floor((maxLenIndex - maxLen) / 2);
  const end = start + maxLen;

  //return the longest palindromic substring
  return string.substring(start, end);
}

console.log(longestPalindromicSubstring("abaxyzzyxf"));
```